# Как реализовать функцию с использованием модуля openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

Пробовала реализовать функцию, которая принимает безграничное количество аргументов в виде текстовых файлов, и данные каждого из них записывает в столбцы таблицы Excel, по принципу: строки одного файла в столбец А (если несколько предложений, то ложим в ячейки А1, А2...по предложению), строки следующего файла в столбец В (В1, В2) и так далее.

Делала много попыток, у меня не получалось. Остановилась пока на таком варианте:

```
def write_to_Excel_args(*args): # DONE

    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()# Новый файл
    sheet = wb.active

    ws_new = openpyxl.Workbook() # Новый файл
    new_sheet = ws_new.active


    for file in args:
        data = open(file)
        text = data.readlines()
        sheet.append(text)# заполнение таблицы построчно

        for row in range(1, sheet.max_row + 1): # отражаем записи по столбцам
            for col in range(1, sheet.max_column + 1):
                new_sheet.cell(col, row).value = sheet.cell(row, col).value

    ws_new.save('Text_from_file_in_args.xlsx')
    print('Записаны по столбцам данные из файлов. Количество файлов = ' + str(len(args)) + '.')
    data.close()
```

Принимаю любые комментарии по данному коду. Считаю данный вариант не совсем правильным.
Может быть кто-нибудь захочет поделиться своим вариантом, или логикой более лучшего варианта реализации кода, буду весьма благодарна!